# Error creating AdHoc profile on iOS Provisioning Portal

Tags: ios, provisioning

Whenever I try to edit existing or create new distribution provisioning profile on iOS Provisioning Portal, the status of the new profile turns to "Pending" and then almost immediately to "Error" (see the screenshot below).

What may be the cause for this? Why can't I edit profiles?

[image]

Comment: Now the Status changed to "Pending" for everyone. It seems like Apple is working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops. It seems like a problem with Apple portal:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/680208

Answer (score 1):

[iOS Provisioning Portal gives error when I try to add a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112292/ios-provisioning-portal-gives-error-when-i-try-to-add-a-profile)

This issue is also the same as above, I was also on my way to ask about this, I think everybody is having a problem.

See UrK answer for the link to a forum where people are talking about it

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after adding the new device. I thought, I can't add the particular device to the device list. I tried deleting the device and recreate the profile, but the same error I got.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/155483?start=0&tstart=0

I saw that on the apple forum lot of developers are facing the same issue. As every body is facing the same problem then we have to wait till the issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS Provisioning Portal says**

> We are performing maintenance on the provisioning service. All
>   provisioning requests will remain in pending status until maintenance
>   is complete, at which time all pending requests will be automatically
>   processed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple said, they needed to put the Provisioning Portal into mainanace. It should now be fixed. Pofiles can be changed and downloaded again.