# iOS Provisioning Portal gives error when I try to add a profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I can't figure out what is causing this generic error in the provisioning portal.  There's no explanation given, and I am clueless.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

[image: error in provisioning portal]

Comment: Me too.  Interesting that your question is 1 hour ago.  Maybe something on the blink at Apple.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(same as this) [Error creating AdHoc profile on iOS Provisioning Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112051/error-creating-adhoc-profile-on-ios-provisioning-portal/)

This issue is also the same as above, I was also on my way to ask about this, I think everybody is having a problem

The above link also has a link directed to dev forums where people are talking about it. I didn't put the link here to give credit for the original one who posted it.